# How do you export python data to excel using xlwt?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request, xlwt

Here is my scrape:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'http://www.baseballpress.com/lineups'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')

for names in soup.find_all(class_="players"):
    print(names.text)
```

I want to import my scrape to excel using xlwt. I used this code below to see if I could make an excel sheet using python:

```
import xlwt  

wb = xlwt.Workbook()  
ws = wb.add_sheet("Batters")  
ws.write(0,0,"coding isn't easy")  
wb.save("myfirst_xlwt")
```

The code above worked. I would now like to apply it to my original scrape. How do I merge these two codes?

I am new so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time! =)

Comment: I don't have xlwt here but you can try [this](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2014/03/24/creating-microsoft-excel-spreadsheets-with-python-and-xlwt/) tutorial

Comment: Thanks @Nullman!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to run your code, but it doesn't find anything with class of `example`. It returns `[]`.

Regarding `xlwt`, basically, it just writes a cell (with the row and column parameter) using a string you specified.

```
wb = xlwt.Workbook() 
ws = wb.add_sheet('sheet_name')
ws.write(0,0,"content") #Writes the first row, first col, in sheet called "sheet_name".
wb.save("example.xls")
```

However, I think `pandas` is just better for that purpose. `xlwt` sometimes gets very messy if you lose track of row number and column number. If you can provide some non-empty result, I can write a simple script for you to export to Excel using pandas.

In order to use `pandas` for your example, here is the code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'http://www.baseballpress.com/lineups'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')

all_games = []

for g in soup.find_all(class_="game"):
    players = g.find_all('a', class_='player-link')
    game = {
        'time': g.find(class_='game-time').text,
        'weather': g.find(target='forecast').text.strip(),
        'players': [_.text for _ in g.find_all('a', class_='player-link')],
    }
    all_games.append(game)

print(all_games) # This will print out a list of dict that contains the game information

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(all_games) # Construct dataframe from the list of dict
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('baseball.xlsx') # Init Pandas excel writer, using the file name 'baseball.xlsx'
df.to_excel(writer, 'baseball_sheet') # Writes to a sheet called 'baseball_sheet'. Format follows the Dataframe format.
writer.save() # Save excel
```

Comment: Sure :) Would be great if you can accept the answer

Comment: I adjusted the code again @MartinLiu... I am not sure if that is what you wanted. Can you please explain your question further? Thanks again =) I will have to look into using pandas.

Comment: Edited my code. Pandas is simpler if you just want to export everything to Excel. All you need to do is to build a list of dicts, then convert it to a pandas DataFrame.

Comment: I would love to get the players names instead of the weather. Is this easy to do?

Comment: Glad to help. Edited my code. Yeah the website structure is very straightforward, all you need to do is find the tag (<a> in this case), and some way to identify it (all of the players has `class` of "player-link")

Comment: Wow!!! =) I really can't thank you enough for all your help. I will spend time studying the code to see if I can understand why you chose the steps you did. @MartinLiu... Thanks again!!!

Comment: It looks like the new code works perfectly on my python shell... But I don't see the excel file get created this time. The file was created perfectly last time. Any suggestions? Thanks again for all your help @MartinLiu... I am very grateful sir.

Comment: Maybe try to look for the directory you are in while using Python shell? Or you can add the absolute path in `writer = pd.ExcelWriter('baseball.xlsx')`.

Comment: I reset my computer and it worked perfectly... Thanks again for your time and patience!!! =) You are the man!

Comment: Where did you find the class "game"? @MartinLiu...I see player-link, game-time, and forecast...

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to merge the snippets would be to use [`ws.write`](http://xlwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#xlwt.Worksheet.Worksheet.write) any place you have a [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) statement. You can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to keep track of your row index:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import xlwt  

wb = xlwt.Workbook()  
ws = wb.add_sheet("Batters")  

url = 'http://www.baseballpress.com/lineups'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')

for row, name in enumerate(soup.find_all(class_="players")):
    ws.write(row, 0, name.text)
wb.save("myfirst_xlwt")
```

Comment: Ty!!! @MadPhysicist =) I appreciate the feedback a lot. I will test that out soon...

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xboss/Desktop/Baseball_Sheet_Code.py", line 12, in <module>
    for row, name in soup.find_all(class_="players"):
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)

Comment: Any idea why I would get that error @MadPhysicist? Sorry... I am a beginner.

Comment: Because I forgot to add `enumerate` like I advertised. My mistake. Fixed now.

Comment: Thank you sir for your time! I am very thankful for your help. =)